# How can I convert Top:50% to Top:305px (or so) with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that if you set a style as a percent with jquery it changes it into pixels.

How can I do this with javascript?

**EDIT**

```
elem.style.left = document.body.style.width / 2;
elem.style.top = document.body.style.height / 2;
```

Returns 0 for both

Comment: `height of the container / 2`?

Comment: As Itay said, you need to find the height of the element and divide it in half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `document.body`

```
elem.style.top = Math.floor(document.body.offsetHeight / 2) + 'px'
```